# Help me deduce limit from differential inequality

Tags: inequality

My friend asked my this question while I was studying for an unrelated exam:

We know that function $a$ is continuously differentiable and defined for $x> 1.$ We have:

> $a'(x)<0$ and $a'(x)> -\frac{a(x)}{x}$ anywhere. 
>   What is the limit $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}a(x)$ ?

My first reaction was **we can't tell**. I thought since the derivative is negative, $a$ must be monotonously decreasing. This excludes positive infinity. I sayed the equation given is equivalent to

$a'(x)x +  a(x) > 0$

This is equivalent to
$[a(x)x]' >0$

From this - and this must have been my mistake, for I haven't been able to connect it to the quotient of limits - I surmised $a(x)$ decreased slower than $\frac{1}{x}$. Thus I excluded negative infinity.

Now I excluded any real value, because all equations are invariant under addition of positive constant to $a$.

Can you help me fix my argumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ is decreasing and $x \to x a(x)$ is increasing, therefore
$$
 \frac{x a(x)}{y} < a(y) < a(x) \text{ for } 1 < x < y \, .
$$
Taking the limit $y \to \infty$ for fixed $x > 1$ it follows that
$a(x) \ge 0$.

So $a$ is monotonically decreasing and non-negative, therefore
$\lim_{x\to\infty}a(x)$ *exists.*

But that is all one can conclude, the limit can be *any* non-negative number $c$, as one sees from the example
$$
 a(x) = c + \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \quad (x > 0)
$$